# Realm: create global configuration for database name

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, realm

I have the following code:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    var config = Realm.Configuration()

    config.fileURL = config.fileURL!.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent?
        .URLByAppendingPathComponent("HelloWorld.realm")

    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config

    return true
}
```

I'm setting the default name for the Realm in the `AppDelegate`. However this name/config isn't loaded when I create a new Realm object in my ViewController like so:

```
    class LoadingScreenViewController: UIViewController {

    let realm = try! Realm()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //The config (HelloWorld.realm) is printed
        print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration)

        //The config (default.realm) is printed
        print(self.realm.configuration)    
    }
}
```

Maybe it's because my ViewController realm is a new object that has it's own state. If that's the case, should I make a Singleton? And if I do so, wouldn't that mean I couldn't handle async writes to the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's nothing wrong with your configuration , you can change the way you creat it .

```
lazy var realm :Realm = {
    var realm = try! Realm()
    return realm
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //The config (HelloWorld.realm) is printed
    print(realm.configuration)
}
```

or

```
var realm :Realm!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    realm = try! Realm()
    //The config (HelloWorld.realm) is printed
    print(realm.configuration)
}
```

maybe `let realm = try! Realm()` with a member var will cause something wrong

hope it be helpful :D